# Having this 2 error mysqli_stmt::bind_param() & Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

Tags: php

Having issue with `mysqli_stmt::bind_param()` and

> Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

errors

```
    // From the SQL query that returns the top 10 most loan asset in the selected asset
    $assetQuery = "SELECT asset_name, num_loan FROM asset ORDER BY asset_name DESC LIMIT 10";

    // Prepare the query statement
    $assetPrepStmt = $dbhandle->prepare($assetQuery);

    // If there is an error in the statement, exit with an error message
    if($assetPrepStmt === false) {
        exit("Error while preparing the query to fetch data from asset Table. ".$dbhandle->error);
    }

    // Bind the parameters to the query prepared
    $assetPrepStmt->bind_param("s", $assetName);

    // Execute the query
    $assetPrepStmt->execute();

    // Get the results from the query executed
    $assetResult = $assetPrepStmt->get_result();
```

Comment: Do you even need a bind_param? Did you miss a where clause which accepts a dynamic param?

Comment: "*contains one or more characters which specify the types for the corresponding bind variables...The number of variables and length of string types **must match the parameters in the statement***" from [mysqli-stmt.bind-param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: Your query does not contain any parameter to bind to